# Using custom stack/rootfs in PCF Dev

Tags: rootfs, pcfdev

A default stack in [PCF Dev](https://pivotal.io/pcf-dev) is [cflinuxfs2](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cflinuxfs2) (based on Ubuntu 14.04). But I would like to use a custom stack (specifically [cflinuxfs3](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cflinuxfs3) based on Ubuntu 18.04).

I have built it successfully (also created a corresponding BOSH release), but I am unable to register it to my PCF Dev environment. The problem seems to be that PCF Dev does not [support BOSH Director](https://docs.pivotal.io/pcf-dev/#comparing-pcf-dev-to-pivotal-cloud-foundry).

I have also tried to use the [CF Stack API](http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/1.24.0/stacks/create_a_stack.html), partially succeeded in registering a new stack (name and description), but was not able to upload the actual rootfs tarball.

Could anyone help me how to properly upload a custom stack to PCF Dev?

Answer (score 0):

It has been my experience that PCF Dev is mainly suitable for application development. If you want to create any bosh release, you should be using bosh lite.

I highly recommend you do a bosh lite setup with cloud foundry, and you can adjust anything you want in that setup. I have been able to do that based on bosh lite instructions and cloud foundry instructions. And I recommend you use https://github.com/starkandwayne/bucc to help you get started with bosh lite, and then add cf on top.